# Pipe file from container in k8s to local machine, edit and copy back to container in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, vim

I need to update a file in a container running in k8s using my local editor and save back the updates to the original file in the container *without* restarting/redeploying the container.

Right now I do:

```
$ kubectl exec tmp-shell -- cat /root/motd > motd && vi motd && kubectl cp motd tmp-shell:/root/motd
```

Is there some better way to do this?

I have looked at:

https://github.com/ksync/ksync

but seems heavyweight for something this "simple".

**Notice:**

I don't want to use the editor that might or might *not* be available inside the container - since an editor is not guaranteed to be available.

Comment: Containers are not really supposed to be used like that.

Comment: He probably wants to just debug. It's a legit question.

Answer (score 1):

One option that might be available is [ephemeral debug containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container) however they are an alpha feature so probably not enabled for you at time of writing. Barring that, yeah what you said is an option. It probably goes without saying but this is a very bad idea, might not work at all if the target file isn't writable (which it shouldn't be in most cases) either because of file permissions, or because the container is running in immutable mode. Also this would only matter if the thing using the file will detect the change without reloading.

A better medium term plan would be to store the content in the ConfgMap and mount it into place. That would let you update it whenever you want.

Comment: Yes agree to all of the above unfortunately reading from configmap and all the other best practice approaches are not really possible in the scenario I am trying to solve

Comment: You could use a ReadWriteMany volume and mount the volume somewhere you can edit it directly. Or use a sidecar that has an editor installed with a shared emptyDir. Both of those might require an initContainer to copy the file from the normal image though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/waverage/kubelink utility. It is like ksync but simpler and based on `kubectl cp` and `kubectl exec` commands.

Install with command: `pip install kubelink` and then use like:

```
kubelink create --name mypreset --source /Users/bob/myproject --destination /code --namespace default --selector "app=backend"

kubelink watch mypreset
```

Kubelink watches your local files and uploads them to Kubernetes pods when they change.